# Vue.js computed function return nothing

Tags: javascript, foreach, vue.js

I'm practicing with a simple to-do list with `vue.js`. I'm trying to sum all `price` within an array. To do that I wrote a little function inside `computed`,
but something has gone wrong, here is my `js`:

```
var app= new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    message: "Lista della spesa",
    seen: true,
    todos: [
      {msg: 'prezzemolo', price: 10},
      {msg: 'pomodori', price: 20},
      {msg: 'zucchine', price: 5}
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    addToDo: function() {
      if(this.nome && this.prezzo) {
        this.todos.push({msg: this.nome, price: this.prezzo});
      }
      this.nome   = "";
      this.prezzo = "";
    },
    RemoveThis: function(index) {
      this.todos.splice(index,1);
    }
  },
  computed: {
    totale: function() {
      var total = 0;

      this.todos.forEach(function() {
        total += this.todos.price
      });

      return total;
    }
  }
});
```

There is something inside the `forEach` that is breaking the function, anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried a simple for-loop to see the result?

Comment: yep, but i want see with forEach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

inside the callback function that you passed to `forEach`, `this` does nto point to the component, it is `undefined` by default.

https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

the callback function receives each `todo` as the argument, so an example would look like this:

```
totale: function(){
  var total = 0;
  this.todos.forEach(function (todo) {
    total += todo.price
  });
  return total;
}
```

Generally, I would not use forEach, I would use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce). Together with an arrow function it becomes a nice one-liner:

```
totale: function () {
  return this.todos.reduce((sum, todo) => sum + todo.price, 0)
}
```

Comment: There is no price attribute on `this.todos`

Comment: Yeah, spotted my mistake a second after and corrected it.

Comment: another thing, i suppose is more vue.js related,
is correct to put that forEach in computed?
Because when i add a price to an array it don't sum, it "concatenate"

like 10+20 = 1020

Comment: that has probbably more to do with the fact that values from `<input>` elements are strings. you have to use `v-model.number="..."` to make Vue turn it into a number (if you use v-model).

Answer (score 3):

Wrong use of `forEach`

e.g.

```js
var total = 0;
var arrayOfObjects = [{price: 10},{price: 20},{price : 30}];

// Correct usage:
arrayOfObjects.forEach(function(obj) {
  total += obj.price;
})

console.log(total)
```

Refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach?v=control

Answer (score 0):

Replace code

```
this.todos.forEach(function(){
    total += this.todos.price
  });
```

to

```
this.todos.forEach(function(data){
    total += data.price
  });
```